# C++ win32 API Window won't update on WindowUpdate

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I have a program that is supposed to display a count that increments every second. The counter is in a separate thread. I call WindowUpdate when a change has occurred but the count in the window does not update unless I hover the mouse pointer over the window or resize the window. I have tried InvalidateRect and RedrawWindow  but they don't work either.

Why won't the counter updates display?

```
    #ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    #endif
    #include <sdkddkver.h>
    #include <Windows.h>

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <tchar.h>
    #include <strsafe.h>

    typedef struct DataTransfer {
        BOOL Updated;
        int Counter;
    } TRANSFER, *PTRANSFER;

    TRANSFER Payload;
    PTRANSFER pPayload;
    DWORD dwThreadId;
    HANDLE hThread;

    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    void DisplayData(HDC hDC);
    void ErrorHandler(LPTSTR lpszFunction);
    DWORD WINAPI Counter(LPVOID lpParam);

    int
    APIENTRY
    wWinMain(
        HINSTANCE hInstance,
        HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
        LPWSTR lpCmdLine,
        int nShowCmd)
    {
        MSG        msg;  

        WNDCLASSEX wcex;
        ZeroMemory(&wcex, sizeof(wcex));

        wcex.cbSize = sizeof(wcex); 
        wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; 
        wcex.lpszClassName = TEXT("MYFIRSTWINDOWCLASS"); 
        wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
        wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(hInstance, IDC_ARROW); 
        wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
        wcex.hInstance = hInstance; 

        if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
            return 1;

        CREATESTRUCT cs;
        ZeroMemory(&cs, sizeof(cs));

        cs.x = 0; 
        cs.y = 0;
        cs.cx = 200;
        cs.cy = 300;
        cs.hInstance = hInstance; 
        cs.lpszClass = wcex.lpszClassName; 
        cs.lpszName = TEXT("Test");
        cs.style = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;


        HWND hWnd = ::CreateWindowEx(
            cs.dwExStyle,
            cs.lpszClass,
            cs.lpszName,
            cs.style,
            cs.x,
            cs.y,
            cs.cx,
            cs.cy,
            cs.hwndParent,
            cs.hMenu,
            cs.hInstance,
            cs.lpCreateParams);

        if (!hWnd)
            return 1;

        DWORD dwThreadId;
        HANDLE hThread;

        pPayload = (PTRANSFER)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(TRANSFER));
        if (pPayload == NULL)
            ExitProcess(2);
        pPayload->Updated = FALSE;
        pPayload->Counter = 0;

        // Display the window.
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    hThread = CreateThread(
        NULL,   
        0,     
        Counter,     
        pPayload,  
        0,       
        &dwThreadId); 
        if (hThread == NULL)
             ExitProcess(2);

        while (1)
        {
            if (pPayload->Updated == TRUE)
            {
    //          InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, FALSE);
    //          RedrawWindow(hWnd, NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);
                UpdateWindow(hWnd);
            }
            if (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
       }

        ::UnregisterClass(wcex.lpszClassName, hInstance);

        return (int)msg.wParam;
    }

    LRESULT
    CALLBACK
    WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct;
        HDC hDC;

        switch (uMsg)
        {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            ::PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &paintStruct);
            DisplayData(hDC);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &paintStruct);
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            return ::DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }

        return 0;
    }


    void DisplayData(HDC hDC)
    {
        char OutputStr[32];

        sprintf_s(OutputStr, sizeof(OutputStr) - 1, "%d", pPayload->Counter);
        TextOut(hDC, 100, 100, OutputStr, strlen(OutputStr));
    }

    DWORD WINAPI Counter(LPVOID lpParam)
    {
        PTRANSFER pTransfer;

        pTransfer = (PTRANSFER)lpParam;

        while (1)
        {
            pTransfer->Counter++;
            pTransfer->Updated = TRUE;
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    void ErrorHandler(LPTSTR lpszFunction)
    {
        LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
        LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
        DWORD dw = GetLastError();

        FormatMessage(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL,
            dw,
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
            0, NULL);

        lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
            (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
        StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
            LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
            TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"),
            lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

        LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
        LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    }
```

Comment: Calling `Sleep(1000)` will not implement a timer, that ticks at a steady rate. `Sleep` may expire sooner or later than the requested time period. Instead, implement a single-threaded application and set up a timer (see [SetTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906.aspx)). Also, you never seem to reset `pPayload->Updated`. The main issue, however, is, that you only ever check `Updated` after a message has been posted.

Comment: `UpdateWindow` by itself won't do anything, you need to invalidate first (which it seems like you have commented out for some reason).

Comment: You are also not synchronizing accesses to the counter thread's data.`Sleep()` by itself won't cut it.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in your message loop:

```
    while (1)
    {
        if (pPayload->Updated == TRUE) {
            UpdateWindow(hWnd);
        }
        if (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
```

[GetMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx) is synchronous, and doesn't return until a message is available for retrieval. The code sits there, waiting for a message to arrive most of the time, and will not evaluate *pPayload->Updated*. Consequently, no updates happen, until a message arrives. But even then, nothing happens, since [UpdateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167.aspx) sends *"a [WM_PAINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145213.aspx) message to the window **if the window's update region is not empty**.*" `UpdateWindow` by itself doesn't do anything useful.<sup>1)</sup>

You could solve this by reworking your message loop. The following issues need to be addressed:

- A call to [InvalidateRect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002.aspx) must precede the call to `UpdateWindow`.
- Access to the shared data must be synchronized.
- The message loop needs to terminate, when `GetMessage` returns 0 or -1.

None of this is necessary, though. You don't need a background thread. A single-threaded application will do just fine. Just use a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644901.aspx) to trigger updates to the stored value, and the visual representation. Here is a rough sketch for a window procedure implementing a timer-based solution:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    static unsigned __int64 startTime = ::GetTickCount64();
    const UINT_PTR timerId = 1;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        // Start timer when window is created
        ::SetTimer(hWnd, timerId, 1000, nullptr);
        return ::DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    case WM_TIMER: {
        unsigned __int64 currTime = ::GetTickCount64();
        Counter = (currTime - startTime) / 1000;
        // Value changed -> initiate window update
        ::InvalidateRect(hWnd, nullptr, FALSE);
        // Re-start timer
        ::SetTimer(hWnd, timerId, 1000, nullptr);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        ::KillTimer(hWnd, timerId);
        ::PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_PAINT: {
        PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct = {0};
        HDC hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &paintStruct);
        DisplayData(hDC);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &paintStruct);
        }
        return 0;
    default:
        return ::DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A few notes on the implementation:

- The timer uses a fixed time-out value of 1000 milliseconds. This will occasionally skip an update. The error doesn't accumulate, though, as the *Counter* is re-evaluated whenever the timer expires. If you more steady updates, calculate the remaining time-out value based on the *Counter*, *startTime*, and *currTime*.
- *Counter* is the variable that holds the current time in seconds. It is a replacement for `TRANSFER::Counter`, that needs to be accessible from both the window procedure and the rendering code.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *There is another issue with your message loop: It never terminates, and neither does your process. The GUI may disappear, but the process will still show up in Task Manager.*

Answer (score 2):

(**Disclaimer**: This answer was written by the seat of my pants. Please correct me if I made an error somewhere.)

You are not doing what you are trying to do properly.

First, as Jonathan Potter has noted, `UpdateWindow()` by itself will not update the window unless it has an *invalid region*. The `InvalidateRect()` call will invalidate a rectangle. So you need both...

...but in reality you don't really want to call `UpdateWindow()` directly, because it bypasses the Windows drawing model. After calling `InvalidateRect()`, if there are no pending messages next time `GetMessage()` is called, and Windows itself decides it's time to refresh the screen contents with new data, you'll get a `WM_PAINT` message. The system knows when it's best to paint; you'll make your life easier by using it. Only use `UpdateWindow()` when it is vital that you want the window to redraw **right now**.

(The point of the invalid region is also due to the Windows drawing model: drawing can be very expensive, so Windows tries to optimize drawing by only redrawing what is needed. Invalidate only the part of your window that needs to be updated, and you'll get better performance.)

But there is a deeper issue: you do not implement multithreading properly.

Your worker thread is generating data every second and overwriting a shared structure. Your window is reading from that shared structure. There is nothing in place to ensure that only one thread is accessing that shared structure at a time. As a result, you'll wind up with ptential mixed state if your worker thread ever grows from a simple integer to a large and complex data structure.

You need to synchronize your data accesses. Communicate between threads.

How? The obvious method is to use a synchronization object, like a mutex. And you can totally do that.

But there's a better way: since one of your threads has a window, just use a window message! Window messages sent using `SendMessage()` will be received on the window's thread (with the calling thread blocked); messages posted using `PostMessage()` will be placed on the window's thread's message queue.

Plus you can pass not one but *two* pieces of information in that message! Both `wParam` and `lParam` are pointer-sized integers, so just stuff a pointer in one of them and use `SendMessage()` or `PostMessage()`!

But what message do you use? Every* message in the range [`WM_USER`, `WM_APP`) is available to the window class to decide what to use it for, and every message in the range [`WM_APP`, `0xC000`) is for the application to decide what to use it for. So just pick one and use it!

Just remember how `SendMessage()` and `PostMessage()` work. If the data is allocated on the heap, and each piece of data is allocated separately, then it doesn't matter; if the data is a pointer to a local variable, `SendMessage()` is the correct answer; if the data is a numeric value that can fit in a pointer-sized integer, either will work. If you need a response, your worker thread will either need a window of its own or the use of `SendMessage()` to get a value back from the window.

There are lots of ways to do this. It all depends on what data you need to communicate. As the Go programming language's designers say (altered somewhat): don't communicate by sharing data; share data by communicating.

---

*until you call `IsDialogMessage()`, at which point you lose `WM_USER` and `WM_USER + 1` (and possibly `WM_USER + 2` as well?). But that's only three messages out of over 32,000.

Answer (score -1):

i marked my alterations with comment `<<updated`
instead of setting flag Updated, i changed it to be hWnd, and then update the window instantly and directly from the thread

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
#include <sdkddkver.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

typedef struct DataTransfer {
    //BOOL Updated;   // << updated
    int Counter;
    HWND hWnd;        // << updated
} TRANSFER, *PTRANSFER;

TRANSFER Payload;
PTRANSFER pPayload;
DWORD dwThreadId;
HANDLE hThread;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
void DisplayData(HDC hDC);
void ErrorHandler(LPTSTR lpszFunction);
DWORD WINAPI Counter(LPVOID lpParam);

int
APIENTRY
wWinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPWSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nShowCmd)
{
    MSG        msg;  

    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    ZeroMemory(&wcex, sizeof(wcex));

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(wcex); 
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; 
    wcex.lpszClassName = TEXT("MYFIRSTWINDOWCLASS"); 
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW); //<< updated
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance; 

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
        return 1;

    CREATESTRUCT cs;
    ZeroMemory(&cs, sizeof(cs));

    cs.x = 0; 
    cs.y = 0;
    cs.cx = 200;
    cs.cy = 300;
    cs.hInstance = hInstance; 
    cs.lpszClass = wcex.lpszClassName; 
    cs.lpszName = TEXT("Test");

    cs.style = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;


    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        cs.dwExStyle,
        cs.lpszClass,
        cs.lpszName,
        cs.style,
        cs.x,
        cs.y,
        cs.cx,
        cs.cy,
        cs.hwndParent,
        cs.hMenu,
        cs.hInstance,
        cs.lpCreateParams);

    if (!hWnd)
        return 1;

    DWORD dwThreadId;
    HANDLE hThread;

    pPayload = (PTRANSFER)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(TRANSFER));
    if (pPayload == NULL)
        ExitProcess(2);
    //pPayload->Updated = FALSE; //<< updated
    pPayload->hWnd=hWnd;

    pPayload->Counter = 0;

    // Display the window.
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    hThread = CreateThread( NULL,  0, Counter, pPayload,  0, &dwThreadId); 
    if (hThread == NULL)
         ExitProcess(2);


    while (1)
    {
        //    ____[ updated ]_____
         /*
        if (pPayload->Updated == TRUE)
        {

            UpdateWindow(hWnd);
            pPayload->Updated=FALSE;
        }
        */
        int ret=GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);//<< updated
        if(ret==0 || ret==-1)
            break;

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

   }

    UnregisterClass(wcex.lpszClassName, hInstance);

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT
CALLBACK
WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT paintStruct;
    HDC hDC;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &paintStruct);
        DisplayData(hDC);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &paintStruct);

        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}


void DisplayData(HDC hDC)
{
    char OutputStr[32];

    sprintf_s(OutputStr, sizeof(OutputStr) - 1, "%d", pPayload->Counter);
    TextOut(hDC, 100, 100, OutputStr, strlen(OutputStr));
}

DWORD WINAPI Counter(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    PTRANSFER pTransfer;

    pTransfer = (PTRANSFER)lpParam;

    while (1)
    {
        pTransfer->Counter++;
        InvalidateRect(pTransfer->hWnd,NULL,1);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}

void ErrorHandler(LPTSTR lpszFunction)
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL);

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"),
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}
```

Comment: This does not fix the multithreading issues. It still `Sleep()`s, thinking it'll sleep for just long enough that the window will have been invalidated. I do not know if calling `InvalidateRect()` in the middle of `BeginPaint()`/`EndPaint()` will cause issues, but it sure sounds like it might.

Comment: yes, i know, i didn't want to go further to synchronization, i just resolved the update issue as it was the main problem. and the main subject of the question .

Comment: This exchanges one wrong with another. Windows have thread affinity and should only be modified from the owning thread (i.e. the thread that created the window). The real solution here is to use a timer.

Comment: @IInspectable using a timer is a good idea, but it stays as a suggestion. i want to stick to the question as is.

Comment: @andlabs , i am not calling `InvalidateRect` in WM_PAINT, and i shouldn't.

Comment: You may not *think* you're calling `InvalidateRect()` during a `BeginPaint()` block, but you are: what happens when your `WM_PAINT` handler is preempted during the `TextOut()` call, your other thread gets scheduled, and it calls `InvalidateRect()`?

Comment: @IInspectable I am going to assume the asker of this question is using `Sleep()` to simulate a slow-moving process while experimenting with implementing multithreading and that their intended use of a multithreaded program will not need the timer at all...

Comment: @andlabs: That may be the ultimate goal. The question still says: *"I have a program that is supposed to display a count that increments every second."* and this is the question that should be answered.

Comment: @andlabs, it doesn't matter if the tread and WM_PAINT get called in the same time. the problem why  you have not to call InvalidateRect in WM_PAINT is that the code fall in a dead lock (infinity loop)

Comment: IInspectable - fair point. milevyo - yes, I know you're not supposed to do that; I'm saying your code does it by accident!

Comment: I admit that this example of my problem with window updates has many shortcomings and appreciate all of your feedback. The behavior I had described was actually when I was calling `InvalidateRectangle()`. Because `GetMessage()` waits for an event, the rest of my code in `wWinMain` like checking the `pPayload->Counter` synchronization variable doesn't get to execute. To solve the window update problem, I used `PeekMessage()` instead of `GetMessage()`.

Comment: @Tom, it remain one thing. in `pPayload->Updated == TRUE` set it back to false